# Comprehensive list of Splash Screen and Icons for Phonegap

Tags: android, ios, cordova, splash-screen

I'm building a Phonegap application which I want to publish on as many platforms as possible.

I've found some documentation on icons and splash screens on the phonegap site.

https://build.phonegap.com/docs/config-xml

http://wiki.phonegap.com/w/page/36905973/Icons%20and%20Splash%20Screens

But can't find a complete list for someone who wants to publish for all devices on IOS(including iPad3), Android, BlackBerry, and Windows phone.

Can someone post a complete list of icon sizes and splash screen dimensions for all devices on all Phonegap supported OSs?

*EDIT:*

*Also include any data that must be attached in the config.xml or specific names.*

*e.g. gap:platform="ios"*

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap/wiki/App-Icon-Sizes

I found this link with some sizes

Comment: if this list included 16x16 for web favicon and guidelines like rounded corners are needed for andorid and not for ios, that'd be great!

Answer (score 0):

Hi Please find the size on Iphone6 or more

```
  <icon src="res/icons/ios/Icon-83.5@2x.png" width="167" height="167" />
  iPad and iPad mini
  <icon src="res/icons/ios/Icon-76@2x.png" width="152" height="152" />
  iPhone 6s, iPhone 6, iPhone 5, iPhone 4s
  <icon src="res/icons/ios/Icon-60@2x.png" width="120" height="120" />
  iOS 6
  <icon src="res/icons/ios/icon@2x.png" width="114" height="114" />
  iPad 2 and iPad mini
  <icon src="res/icons/ios/Icon-76.png" width="76" height="76" />
   Spotlight search 
  <icon src="res/icons/ios/Icon-60.png" width="60" height="60" />
  iOS6 
  <icon src="res/icons/ios/icon.png" width="57" height="57" />
```